# Can't copy file with php, permission denied

Tags: php, linux, apache, server

I'm trying to copy an uploaded file through php to a folder in the home directory. I gave every permission to the Apache user (www-data) but when I'm trying to copy it I get a warning "**failed to open stream: Permission denied**".

```
copy("$target_file", "/home/pap-x/meshes/Part_A.dae");
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What are the permissions of the source file?

Comment: does www-data have access to $target_file as well? also, why not use [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)?

Comment: @ThomasVdBerge The permissions of the source file are: -rw-r--r--

Comment: @pap-x apache user (www-data) doesn't have permission to write/copy the file in home directory of another user. For that apache user need to have the permission on home directory to copy the file

Comment: @Haridarshan I have given all permissions to the apache user in the directory I'm trying to copy the file in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to www-data having permissions to the directory of $target, it must have at least execute permissions to every directory above the target.  If any of those directories deny access then www-data will not be able to find the target directory.

Comment: That was it, the head folder I was trying to copy the file to didn't have permissions for the www-data user. Thank you!