# php copy() not working with an specific url link

Tags: php, copy

I want to copy an image from an another server, but it doesn't work and i don't know why. Here is my code:

```
if(copy('http://demo.swyp.fr/mod_traffiq/thumb/LQ1009C/LQ143559C/LQ157553C-71x100.jpg', 'zzz.jpg')) {
    echo "Copy success!";
}else{
    echo "Copy failed.";
}
```

It always returns failed.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the [`copy`](http://php.net/copy) function. Although this method works with both remote sources and destinations, you are encouraged to use the `file_put/get_contents`-methods (see documentation quote below).

```
$image = file_get_contents('http://demo.swyp.fr/mod_traffiq/thumb/LQ1009C/LQ143559C/LQ157553C-71x100.jpg');
file_put_contents('zzz.jpg', $image);
```

From the `file_get_contents` documentation:

> file_get_contents() is the preferred way to read the contents of a file into a string. It will use memory mapping techniques if supported by your OS to enhance performance.

Also note:

> A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen wrappers have been enabled.

However, if `fopen` remote URL is not turned on in your settings, you might test with cURL:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://demo.swyp.fr/mod_traffiq/thumb/LQ1009C/LQ143559C/LQ157553C-71x100.jpg');
$fp = fopen('zzz.jpg', 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

There could be other PHP settings (or server configurations) which disables all of these code snippets from running. If this does not work, then it is a matter of configuration issues instead.

Comment: I do as you said, but the copied image is empty :(

Comment: @MInhNHat Did you see the note. This requires you to have fopen enabled. If your server has this disabled, then downloading remote like this is not possible. Check the values in your `phpinfo()`.

Comment: *The copy function only works on local files* - I don't think that's true. It uses the same wrappers that `file_get_contents` would.

Comment: @iainn You are actually correct. Nothing in the `copy` documentation said anything about supporting a remote `$source`, although it states that it works with a remote `$dest`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I have checked the value of 'allow_url_fopen'. It's enabled (on), but the copied image is empty.

Comment: @MInhNHat I included cURL code as well. If none of these snippets work, then it is either an issue with your configuration, or perhaps the remote host disallows your requests.

Comment: `if(fclose(fopen($url, 'r')))copy($url, $filename);` otherwise its permissions or file not available

Comment: @LeoTahk This image is set to 0777.

Comment: @OptimusCrime thanks for your help. I really don't know why is the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35151531/cant-copy-file-with-php-permission-denied need to know your error